# Writing multiple SPARQL queries in Protege

Tags: sparql, protege

I'm writing my SPARQL queries in "snap sparql" of Protege. But when I want to write the second query below the first query, I receive error. It seems it is not possible to write multiple queries in Protege. Right? What should I do?

I try to use owlready2 which is a Python library but it doesn't support "minus" and "or" that I need.

Comment: Please include a minimal example of what you tried, and quote the error message you got.

Comment: you can't execute two or more `SELECT` queries at once. I mean, what would be the result in Protege then? The union of both resultsets? The concatenation?

Comment: `owlready2` does support "or" with `UNION` operator. Or what do you mean by "or"? Are you talking about standard SPARQL or something else?

Comment: @UninformedUser no. I want that my queries execute one after each other. I need to write all my queries in some place (for example in protege) and it executes them one after each other. but in protege I could only write one query

Comment: @UninformedUser yes I mean UNION that concatenates the results

Comment: @UninformedUser I' m talking about standard sparql. standard sparql supports union with || but in owlready2 We can't use ||